# Missing Reference on specific machine using Fody Costura with Topshelf and Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, topshelf, fody-costura, methodnotfound

I have built a little Windows service that runs on a client's machine, connects to a local database and posts that data to a webservice.  I'm using Topshelf with Ninject, and the code is essentially boilerplate, right from the template.  I added Fody Costura to make it simple to deploy, and have successfully deployed it on a number of client machines.  However, on one client machine I'm working with, when I try to run the app or install the service, I get the following error:

```
Topshelf.HostFactory Error: 0 : An exception occurred creating the host, System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Topshelf.HostConfigurators.HostConfigurator Topshelf.Ninject.HostConfiguratorExtensions.UseNinject(Topshelf.HostConfigurators.HostConfigurator, Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[])'.
   at OpiniionDentrixIntegration.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_0(HostConfigurator x)
   at Topshelf.HostFactory.New(Action`1 configureCallback)
Topshelf.HostFactory Error: 0 : The service terminated abnormally, System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Topshelf.HostConfigurators.HostConfigurator Topshelf.Ninject.HostConfiguratorExtensions.UseNinject(Topshelf.HostConfigurators.HostConfigurator, Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[])'.
   at OpiniionDentrixIntegration.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_0(HostConfigurator x)
   at Topshelf.HostFactory.New(Action`1 configureCallback)
   at Topshelf.HostFactory.Run(Action`1 configureCallback)
```

For some reason this specific machine (Windows 7, .NET 4.6.2) can't find the supposedly embedded Topshelf.Ninject.dll which contains the missing method.  I've attempted to add the dll a number of places, removed and readded the reference, and stripped down the app to the bare minimum, and still this one machine is having problems.  What could be happening that this one random reference is being missed on this one random machine?

Comment: try purging the nuget cache on that machine

Comment: also confirm that all the machines have the same version of .net